# Static ArrayList from a service is empty when accessed from my MainActivity

Tags: java, android

I am making a basic app that just reads RSS files from google and displays the headlines in a listview. The problem I am having is that the static ArrayList I am using in an IntentService is empty when I access it after I start the intent for the service. There could be something very basic I am missing here but tit used to work before I added more RSS links to the service. I tried commenting them out to see if there was some sort of overloading somewhere but nothing changed, which I guess means that I changed something else without realizing or remembering it.

Here is my relavent code, the ArrayList I am trying to access is the newsList variable in RSSsearcher. In the past I have logged the string values of the arraylist and confirmed that it was being populated in the RSSsearcher class, but empty in the MainActivity class.

Relevant code:

RSSsearcher:

```
public class RSSsearcher extends IntentService {
    public static ArrayList<NewsCard> newsList = new ArrayList<>();
    private static String TAG = "RSS";

    public RSSsearcher() {
        super("RSSsearcher");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        parseNewsLists();
        Log.i(TAG,"newsList in onHandleIntent" + newsList);
    }

    public static ArrayList<NewsCard> getNewsCards() {
        return newsList;
    }

    //helper method to create all the RSSfeed objects
    private void parseNewsLists() {
        Log.i(TAG, "the service has been started");
        //Creating the RSS feed objects
        RSSfeed topStories = new RSSfeed("https://news.google.com/news?cf=all&hl=en&pz=1&ned=us&output=rss");
        RSSfeed worldNews = new RSSfeed("https://news.google.com/news/rss/headlines/section/topic/WORLD?ned=us&hl=en");
        RSSfeed usNews = new RSSfeed("https://news.google.com/news/rss/headlines/section/topic/NATION?ned=us&hl=en");
        RSSfeed buisnessNews = new RSSfeed("https://news.google.com/news/rss/headlines/section/topic/BUSINESS?ned=us&hl=en");
        RSSfeed technologyNews = new RSSfeed("https://news.google.com/news/rss/headlines/section/topic/TECHNOLOGY?ned=us&hl=en");
        RSSfeed entertainmentNews = new RSSfeed("https://news.google.com/news/rss/headlines/section/topic/ENTERTAINMENT?ned=us&hl=en");
        RSSfeed sportsNews = new RSSfeed("https://news.google.com/news/rss/headlines/section/topic/SPORTS?ned=us&hl=en");
        RSSfeed scienceNews = new RSSfeed("https://news.google.com/news/rss/headlines/section/topic/SCIENCE?ned=us&hl=en");
        RSSfeed healthNews = new RSSfeed("https://news.google.com/news/rss/headlines/section/topic/HEALTH?ned=us&hl=en");

        try {
            //getting RSS feeds
            topStories.FileReader();
            worldNews.FileReader();
            usNews.FileReader();
            buisnessNews.FileReader();
            technologyNews.FileReader();
            entertainmentNews.FileReader();
            sportsNews.FileReader();
            scienceNews.FileReader();
            healthNews.FileReader();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }
        //adding stories to main
        newsList.addAll(topStories.getNews());
        newsList.addAll(worldNews.getNews());
        newsList.addAll(usNews.getNews());
        newsList.addAll(buisnessNews.getNews());
        newsList.addAll(technologyNews.getNews());
        newsList.addAll(entertainmentNews.getNews());
        newsList.addAll(sportsNews.getNews());
        newsList.addAll(scienceNews.getNews());
        newsList.addAll(healthNews.getNews());
    }

}
```

MainActivity:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //TODO remove and have actual tags show up
        TagCard onecard = new TagCard("TestCard");
        TagCard twocard = new TagCard("TestCard2");

        dummyTags.add(onecard);
        dummyTags.add(twocard);

        mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_content_list);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
        tagDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.tag_drawer);

        //setting an intent for the RSSsearcher to fetch the news
        //TODO make this happen every 15 minutes or so
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RSSsearcher.class);
        startService(intent);

        NewsCard card = new NewsCard("Testing", "linkeroni");

        //adding all the NewsCard objects to this classes newsList
        newsList.addAll(RSSsearcher.getNewsCards());

        MainAdapter adapter = new MainAdapter(this, newsList);
        mainListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        Log.i(TAG, "This is the array from main activity" + newsList.toString());

        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer){

            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getActionBar().setTitle("Closed");
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View view){
                super.onDrawerOpened(view);
                getActionBar().setTitle("Open");
            }
        };

        //TODO removed dummytags and add actual tag implementation
        tagDrawerList.setAdapter(new TagAdapter(this,dummyTags));

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just because you start your intent service does not mean it has everything by the time you do this `newsList.addAll(RSSsearcher.getNewsCards());`. Accessing data in this was is not really a good idea

Comment: `buisnessNews` is misspelled.

Comment: Tyczj, the reason I wanted it with a service is because I want the app to continually get the RSS feeds every hour or so in the background, I haven't added that part in yet though. Is there a better way to do it? Lew Bloch, so it is. EDIT I didn't finish typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that when you call

```
newsList.addAll(RSSsearcher.getNewsCards());
```

The intent is still in execution

Comment: Is there anyway I can wait for the intent to finish executing or do it in another task? If I did it in an AsyncTask then I could still have the same problem since its in a separate thread right?